# Google FIT API Unlink to Google API without the Account

Tags: google-fit

How to remove link of the application id to the google api that is tied to google fit?

I do not have the account that was use to to create the OAuth 2.0

Comment: Could you please give more details about your use case?

Comment: Are you asking how to revoke an application's access to your Google Fit data? https://myaccount.google.com/permissions